# Google now Hotel reservation (LodgingReservation) image markup

Tags: json, gmail, schema.org, google-schemas, google-now

I'm trying to insert a google now hotel reservation card using lodgingReservation schema in my hotel's confirmation email.
It seems working all, but in my iphone I can't see the hotel image I've insert in the json.
I read all the google documentation but I didn't find a working example with image display of an hotel reservation, only an image of the final result.
Here's an example:

```
<html>
  <head>
            <script type=3D"application/ld+json">   
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "LodgingReservation",
        "reservationNumber": "20161",
        "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
        "underName": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "Mario Rossi",
            "email": "demo@gmail.com"
        },
        "reservationFor": {
            "@type": "LodgingBusiness",
            "name": "Hotel Beverly",
            "address": {
                "@type": "PostalAddress",
                "streetAddress": "Viale Portofino 2",
                "addressLocality": "Rimini",
                "addressRegion": "RN",
                "postalCode": "47833",
                "addressCountry": "IT"
            },
            "telephone": "+390541375288",
            "contactPoint" : {
                "@type" : "ContactPoint",
                "telephone" : "+390541375288",
                "contactType" : "Reception",
                "email" : "info@beverlyhotel.com",
                "faxNumber" : "+390541372288"
            }
        },
        "checkinDate": "2016-02-04T12:00:00-08:00",
        "checkoutDate": "2016-02-08T10:00:00-08:00"
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Google Now card in Gmail test.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've insert an example url of an image, in google documentation I didn't find any word to explain the usage of the image item (min and max width and height ecc...).

I've used the example of @Franco and here's the google app result and the google calendar result (in calendar I don't have idea where google take the photo...)

[image: example of google app on ios]

[image: Example of google calendar result]

Comment: Testing on a iPhone 6, I wasn't able to get a Now card with your image, however, your image did appear in Inbox (http://i.stack.imgur.com/fR2mn.jpg). Maybe you could try testing on a Android device? I couldn't find anything about image specifications on the online articles. None of the examples use image, so I can't see what size image they recommend.

Comment: I have an iphone 6 but i'm going to test with an android device in this days...
Where did you see in inbox the card with the image? Gmail?
For the image specification google documentation is very poor...

Answer (score 0):

After researching more, I came to the conclusion that the Now card will not parse the image in your markup, but will use an image from the hotel's Google + page.

I've conducted a test with Grand Hotel et de Milan and UNA Hotel Cusani (I could not find Hotel Beverly di Rimini anywhere). My markup below (no **image** property) generated a Now card with an image from the Grand Hotel et de Milan  [Google + page](https://plus.google.com/107307629601213475439/photos) (1st pic in the photo section):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LodgingReservation",
  "reservationNumber": "GHM123",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "underName": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Mario Rossi",
    "email": "example@gmail.com"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type": "LodgingBusiness",
    "name": "Grand Hotel et de Milan",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": "Via Alessandro Manzoni, 29",
      "addressLocality": "Milano",
      "addressRegion": "IT",
      "postalCode": "20121",
      "addressCountry": "IT"
    },
    "telephone": "+3902123456789",
    "contactPoint" : { 
      "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "++39 02 723141",
      "contactType" : "Reception",
      "email" : "info@reception.com"
    }
  },
  "checkinDate": "2016-01-21T12:00:00-08:00",
  "checkoutDate": "2016-01-25T10:00:00-08:00"
}
</script>
```

This is the Now card result on a iPhone 6 (note I also received the same result when using UNA Hotel Cusani):

[image]

**Update 2/5/16**:

I was able to generate a Now card with the Beverly logo which looks it's the "profile" image on the Google + page. I didn't use the *image* field.  Additionally, the image generated in Inbox was a picture from the Google + as well. My test script below with pictures of the results:

```html
  <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LodgingReservation",
  "reservationNumber": "abcdef123456",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "underName": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Mario Rossi",
    "email": "example@gmail.com"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type": "LodgingBusiness",
    "name": "Hotel Beverly",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": " Viale Portofino, 2",
      "addressLocality": "Rimini",
      "addressRegion": "RN",
      "postalCode": "47924",
      "addressCountry": "IT"
    },
    "telephone": "+3902123456789",
    "contactPoint" : { 
      "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "+3902123456789",
      "contactType" : "Reception",
      "email" : "info@reception.com",
      "faxNumber" : "+3902123456789"
    }
  },
  "checkinDate": "2016-02-04T16:00:00-08:00",
  "checkoutDate": "2016-02-06T10:00:00-08:00"
}
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: ok but how the card can take the google plus photo without any link at the page?
Maybe the name of the hotel and address must be the same of the google+ (google mybusiness better) page?

Comment: I'm not sure how the card takes the photo from the G+/Mybusiness page. I do suspect it searches the hotel name and address like you mentioned. The fields in my markup above were exact to what the + page has. Let me know how your testing goes.

Comment: Now my email is whitelisted... I've insert the same name, address of my google plus page, but google only show the map, not the image of the hotel. I've seen in my card it isn't the row "Hotel information" but the first is "Find directions"

Comment: @DellaeMme Cool to hear your email is active now. I'd like to try and replicate what you're receiving. Could you update the markup in your question with what you've recently used to test?

Comment: I've updated the example, the name, address ecc is the same of the google page, It's very strange I don't see in my card the Hotel information field...

Comment: @DellaeMme Check out  my update on the answer. I was able to generate the logo on the Now card. I didn't use the image field in my script. Try testing out my test script I've posted.

Comment: Wow, in your's example it's present also the hotel information field.
In what device and app you see the result? I'm using google app for ios and an iphone 6...

Comment: @DellaeMme same exact device and app as you. The second screenshot was on my desktop logged into Google Inbox (https://inbox.google.com). Let me know if you're able to get the same result.

Comment: @DellaeMme Oh cool man. It looks like we've got different pictures in our results. I'm not sure how it's determined. Are these the types of results you're looking for?

Comment: I was looking for yours result. Maybe it's because I'm in Italy and here google card it's not totally supported?

Comment: @DellaeMme According to this article (https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6245953?hl=en), Italy should be supported.