# Google Inbox Event with image url, when converted to Trip image disappears

Tags: google-schemas

I received a mail in google inbox which was correctly interpreted as an event. This event had a image and was also correctly shown.

This event was interpreted as a trip as i wanted it to happen. But the image of the event disappeared. Now I see the default image for a HotelReservation.

```
{
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
   "@type": "LodgingReservation",
   "reservationNumber":"2016_07",
   "bookingTime":"2016-06-03",
   "lodgingUnitDescription":"standplaats, elektriciteit, annulatieverzekering",
   "numAdults":2,
   "numChildren":0,
   "price":"485",
   "priceCurrency": "EUR",
   "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
   "underName": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "Rogge Suzan"
   },
   "reservationFor": {
      "@type": "LodgingBusiness",
      "name": "Camping La Ferme des Aulnes",
      "url": "http://www.fermedesaulnes.com/",
      "image": "http://www.fermedesaulnes.com/medias/images/pages/accueil/camping-somme.jpg",
      "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "Fresne",
          "addressLocality": "Nampont, France",
          "postalCode": "80120",
          "addressCountry": "FR"
      },
      "telephone": "+33 3 22 29 22 69"
   },
  "modifiedTime": "2016-06-09",
  "checkinDate": "2016-07-24",
  "checkoutDate": "2016-08-07"
}
```

Update:
I tried using a smaller image: [smaller-image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/JN1n1vdh3xB4sbBMXEWN0zVChEExQzLOP3MQq4yvMYSXgdm17ljftiu7_7e5MTGQXwnaBqaYocWTkChwyOiqw4HW0YzaDgCeLL_iRIx4iH4lv5n60yVHxd9xCOylFwjZg8DMB7hiIkOG7PNgvm-WuxSq4UPQ-ub7ccs3Ts2YCH4hS4gH70uSMmApdpg0xjZLxVAHx50ttRKHE6yaaKQPRNdfeu6f8RhjVrOi_W6LOV01AYw4Tp4OM3aQd9lbWXNL86HUPCxvTwP-Ph-FEru6TxWgR4nH8_PfmBJLllvCTZxCs2dLgx-a_aSGOCiH5Gim4H_yPU6wjA0m6eG8GTUnDEtFEzEejC2hHsRkIrTTzS0FCirnMWk17MZSTAtyO75hlQFfCBlYFJ3pcy1Nr3xiQ-sfBflbeEapK4bFHXHWpTmAhl-mUnIWFRsy_boNW5ZQVFcIKdmwqlbDybt7EMCvgkUCGwWWfNXz_KbuWk8UkCuSQdHRHJHai3Ov7qsYjwrNFMR1Def-kYLB-j3LTnkBjDeKRpHYaS8pdsotReeGoEo24ElYfAIIhLfbRNKwUu4FENZYxl1K2LsnXVptRdQ5yOqrHB0milw=w401-h205-no), but i get the same result, first I see the event with the image and a minute later the image disappears.

Comment: You can check out a similar issue here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842570/google-now-hotel-reservation-lodgingreservation-image-markup). It seems that when using the image attribute, the image will show up for a bit, but then disappear. I ran tests without using the image attribute and it seems that the image shown is selected from the LodgingBusiness Google + for Business account.

Comment: @Franco That could be, there is no image on the G+ page of that business, that's why I wanted to specify a custom image.

Answer (score 0):

Schema image property can have a url or an ImageObject as value.

```
`body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
img itemprop="url" src="https://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
meta itemprop="height" content="20" />
meta itemprop="width" content="20" />
/div>

/body>`
```

Some content management systems provide widgets or plugins that inject [event](https://schema.org/Event) markup into a page. If your content management system uses one of the following, it should generate event markup that meets Google Search requirements.

The table below shows required and recommended properties for events. Define each event using a specific applicable subtype of schema.org/Event. Popular subtypes include:

- ComedyEvent
- Festival
- FoodEvent
- MusicEvent
- TheaterEvent
- SportsEvent

For more information regarding Google Schemas check this: https://developers.google.com/schemas/tutorials/embedding-schemas-in-emails

Answer (score 0):

@Sabine, try using an image that is smaller. The image you used is 1215 x 620. I did a test with a smaller [image](http://www.weekend-espritdepicardie.com/sites/picardiev3/files/1-fun-Ferme-des-Aulnes-CRTP-Nicolas-Bryant--16-.jpg) (440 x 330). It looks like Inbox doesn't like large images. Script below with the [image](http://www.weekend-espritdepicardie.com/sites/picardiev3/files/1-fun-Ferme-des-Aulnes-CRTP-Nicolas-Bryant--16-.jpg) I used:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">   
    {
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
   "@type": "LodgingReservation",
   "reservationNumber":"ABC123",
   "bookingTime":"2016-06-03",
   "lodgingUnitDescription":"standplaats, elektriciteit, annulatieverzekering",
   "numAdults":2,
   "numChildren":0,
   "price":"485",
   "priceCurrency": "EUR",
   "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
   "underName": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "Rogge Suzan"
   },
   "reservationFor": {
      "@type": "LodgingBusiness",
      "name": "Camping La Ferme des Aulnes",
      "url": "http://www.fermedesaulnes.com/",
      "image": "http://www.weekend-espritdepicardie.com/sites/picardiev3/files/1-fun-Ferme-des-Aulnes-CRTP-Nicolas-Bryant--16-.jpg",
      "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "Fresne",
          "addressLocality": "Nampont, France",
          "postalCode": "80120",
          "addressCountry": "FR"
      },
      "telephone": "+33 3 22 29 22 69"
   },
  "modifiedTime": "2016-06-09",
  "checkinDate": "2016-07-24",
  "checkoutDate": "2016-08-07"
    }
    </script>
```

Result:

[image]